# How to add MapQuest RouteLayer to leaflet layer

Tags: javascript, web, leaflet

i want to implement in my leaflet app, feature that allows to find route between two selected points.To find route i want to use this library: [mapquest](https://developer.mapquest.com/)
I have extended standard leaflet map class like this:

```
export class Map {
constructor(elementId, centerView, zoom ) {
        this.layers = [];
        this.map = this.init(elementId,centerView,zoom);
        this.icons = {};
    }
        init(elementId, centerView, zoom) {
        //console.log('Map::init('+elementId+', ['+centerView+'], '+zoom+')');
        delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;

        const markerIcon = require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png');
        const markerIcon2x = require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png');
        const markerShadow = require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png');

        L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
            iconRetinaUrl: markerIcon2x.default,
            iconUrl: markerIcon.default,
            shadowUrl: markerShadow.default,
        });

        var map = L.map(elementId, {
            center: [centerView[0], centerView[1]],
            zoom: zoom
        });        

        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org         /copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        return map;
    }
}
```

And i wrote few functions that helps me to work with map(add point, markers etc).
This is how i'm initializing extended map object:

```
let centerView = [35.791188, -78.636755];
let zoom = 9;
var map = new Map('map', centerView, zoom);
```

And i found code how to generate route [mapquest-routing](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/routing/).I'am taking coords by clicking on map which works fine. My function to generate route looks like this:

```
 function runDirection(start, end) 
    {
        var dir = MQ.routing.directions();

        dir.route({
            locations: [
                start,
                end
            ]
        });
        
        map.map.addLayer(MQ.routing.routeLayer({
            directions: dir,
            fitBounds: true
```

}));
}

But i'm getting error:

> Uncaught Error: The provided object is not a Layer.

Which means MQ.routing.routeLayer(),doesnt return me leyer object.
So the question is, how can i add route to standard leaflet map?

Comment: So, what's the return value of `MQ.routing.routeLayer(...)`, then?

Comment: https://developer.mapquest.com/docs/api-reference/leaflet-plugins/classes/MQ.Routing.RouteLayer.html

Comment: screenshot from console: https://ibb.co/zNpHFT5

Comment: OK, and which JS file are you loading for the mapquest stuff?  `https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-routing.js` or `https://api.mqcdn.com/sdk/mapquest-js/v1.3.2/mapquest.js`?

Comment: These 2:
https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-map.js?key=my_key">

https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-routing.js?key=my_key

Answer (score 0):

You're using a deprecated library. On the https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/leaflet-plugins/geocoding/ webpage there's a deprecation warning in big red letters, I quote:

> We recommend using [MapQuest.js](https://developer.mapquest.com/documentation/mapquest-js/v1.3/) instead.

The documentation in the webpage for that mapquest plugin for Leaflet lists compatibility for Leaflet 0.7.7 (which was published back on 2013). Leaflet uses [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), which means stuff that worked with 0.x has no guarantee of working with 1.x. It's safe to assume that the Leaflet plugin in question only works with Leaflet 0.7.x and older, and does not work with Leaflet 1.x.

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8dnYNTncoU
which is not that old.

Comment: So? Complain to the creator of that video tutorial for using deprecated libraries then.